# instance of (wdt:P31) OR subclass of (wdt:P279*)

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am querying for food in wikidata with this query

```
SELECT ?item ?label  WHERE { 
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q2095. 
  ?item rdfs:label ?label.

  FILTER(LANG(?label) = 'en')
}
```

It includes food as 'burrito' which is an instance of food ([try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ2095.%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%0A%20%20FILTER%28lcase%28str%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%27burrito%27%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0A%7D))

It includes food as 'paella' (subclass of food) ([try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ2095.%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%0A%20%20FILTER%28lcase%28str%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%27paella%27%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0A%7D))

It won't include  'chicken' ([try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ2095.%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%0A%20%20FILTER%28lcase%28str%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%27chicken%27%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0A%7D)) which is also a subclass of food
It will include 'chicken' when the query is just wdt:P29* ([try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ2095.%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%0A%20%20FILTER%28lcase%28str%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%27chicken%27%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0A%7D)), but then burrito will not be included.

What would be the query for food that would include paella , chicken and burrito ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have oriented the subClassOf and instanceOf parts of this property path may be a little unusual, but it accounts for the fact that chicken is not asserted to be an instance of food in wikidata, unlike the other foods you mentioned.

```
SELECT ?item ?label  WHERE { 
  ?item wdt:P279*/wdt:P31* wd:Q2095. 
  ?item rdfs:label ?label.

  FILTER(LANG(?label) = 'en')
}
```

Comment: No, that would for sure be wrong :D   -> `type/subClassOf*` covers `type wd:Q2095` as well as `type SOME_TYPE. SOME_TYPE subClassOf wd:Q2095` `

Comment: I ran the query at the wikidata web interface and then pasted paella, chicken and burrito into the text search box.  All were found.

Comment: That might be because of OWL punning, but in general the pattern is `rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf*` for RDF resp. here in the Wikidata case `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*`

Comment: Maybe my query works because `wdt:P31*` can be evaluated to a zero-length path of instnacesOf, leaving just a path of 0 or more subClassesOf food?

Comment: The problem is obviously that "chicken" is never used as an instance of food but just a subclass while others are proper instances of food resp. subclasses of food. For example, "chicken" is just a subclass of food, "chicken soup" is an instance of food. That's strange modeling from my point of view nad might confuse people. Indeed your solution covers both cases and should be the accepted answer. Well done!